# Why are all permissions allowed for every user group

Tags: joomla-3.x, permissions

For some reason I can't deny permissions to some actions. Everything has in green: `Allowed (Super User)`. Even when the setting is set to denied.

For example here: in the `public` user group I set site login and admin login to denied but it gets overwritten by something:

[image]

What can I do about this? I am using Joomla 3.8.1 and am on PHP 7.1.33

Comment: Open your browser console and try changing one of the permissions. Do you get any errors? Also check the ajax request in the "Network" tab to see if this returns any errors

Comment: @Lodder I don't have any console errors, every request in my network tab has code `200` except for `https://mywebsite.nl/cms/administrator/index.php?option=com_config` which has `303`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've granted Super User access to Public (4th permission down). Change that to "Not Set" and then reload the web page.